# Jquery UI autocomplete select not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery for autocomplete for my django project. But the on select is not being fired. Here's my code:

```
 <script>
 $(function () {
  $("#product").autocomplete({
      source: '{% url 'discover' %}',
      minLength: 2,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("Selected ");
    },
      
  });
  });
</script>
```

my html code:

```
 <form action="">
 <input id='ticker' type="search" placeholder="&#xF002; Search company" aria-describedby="button-addon4" class="form-control bg-none border-0" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome;height: 60px;width:600px;background-color:rgb(31, 29, 54)">
 </form>
```

and the scripts i use:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and the django part:

```
def discover(request):

if 'term' in request.GET:
    qs = Instrument.objects.filter(name__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
    titles = list()
    for instrument in qs:
        titles.append(instrument.name)
    # titles = [product.title for product in qs]
    return JsonResponse(titles, safe=False)
```

The autocomplete works fine, but for some reason the select event in not triggred. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to run, after the DOM complete load, in that case you only execute when DOM is ready, your script would be like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#product").autocomplete({
      source: '{% url 'discover' %}',
      minLength: 2,
      select: function(event, ui) {
         alert("Selected ");
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did u put before the </body>? Can u check whether it has error in the console log. Thanks

Comment: Yes i did. There's no error in the console.